# validation for primefaces editor

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces

My first problem with primefaces editor is it does not accept the text from a MS word document in chrome and explorer but works fine in Firefox. Is there a way that it directly accept the content from MS word instead of using page as text option in `p:editor`.

My code looks like:

```
   <p:editor id="courseSummary" value="#{course.courseSummary.courseSummary}"    required="true" requiredMessage="#{messageBundle['productManagement.product.descriptionRequired']}"/>
```

My second one is I entered some string value which has many lines and pressed save which stored the value into my backing bean. Then if I manually clear my editor on UI, and if I don't clear the lines, it does not validate but stores in to the string `courseSummary`as   br/>
.
Can someone help me how to go about in this?

Answer (score -1):

CKeditor along with some java script and FacesContext should replace p:editor. Which supports copy from MSWord and HTML content.

```
 FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();       
 Map<String,String> params = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
 reviewCommentsText = params.get("myObj");
```